# Win10: Cannot ping localhost / Windows Smart Screen does not work

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, firewall, localhost

I have an odd problem - I am unable to ping localhost. It just hangs until eventually dies with an error, or returns results. It seems that there is a huge delay in DNS lookup:

[image: DNS lookup ping]

In addition to that issue, the Windows Smart Screen also reports errors that it cannot connect to the Smart Screen server.

[image: smartscreen error]

To add insult to injury, it appears that my Windows firewall is not properly listening either, just results in a blank screen:

[image: Blank screen on windows security]

When loading web sites, some pages load, a lot do not.

Other things to mention:

- I have Malwarebytes Anti Malware installed
- I am using Windows Defender as AV
- I used to use Norton Security
- I have tried using `RKill`
- I cannot stop Malwarebytes from running
- If I load the Windows Firewall page, it just hangs and cancel is grayed out:
  [image: hanging firewall mmc snap-in]
- BleepingComputer forums were no help
- Malwarebytes forums were no help
- Have done an in-place reinstall of windows 10
- Have run SFC
- Have run DISM
- Reboots usually fix this issue, but it always resurfaces after some period of time.
- I have not found a fix outside of rebooting
- I also use Google WiFi, but PC is hard wired on to LAN
- I have several Netgear Managed switches in my network also, but this has never been an issue.

If anyone has any ideas, I am all ears; I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: I read through your list of attempted fixes. Now do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Go to the Windows Media Creation Link  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: @John - "I have done an in-place reinstall of windows 10"

Comment: I missed the comment about doing an in-place Repair in the long list - apologies - and I see you have done it. Given all the above, back up your Documents (All Docs, email, etc) and reinstall Windows.

Comment: It seems as if my firewall is corrupt or defective?

Comment: That could be.  But you have done all the possible fixes to your OS. Firewall is not an app and so not separately installable. so the apparent corruption is bad enough that you need to rebuild the OS.